# accessing session scoped managed bean from another session scoped managed bean

Tags: events, jsf-2

I have a problem with opening a `sessionScoped` managed bean from another.
I have a page that has a table wich contains list of objects.
On row click I am navigating to another page and displaying its contents.
I am sending the clicked row in `sessionMap` object or by `Flash`.
The object is sent and read in the other page and data are displayed.
In the other page I am receiving the `sessionMap` or `Flash` in the `@PostConstruct` method.

If I get back and opened another object the first object will open and the problem is that its a `sessionScoped` bean so on the second opened it will not invoke the `@PostConstruct`.
So what is the solution for forcing the `sessionScoped` to read the new value and open another session?
Or how can I read an object by listener rather than `@PostConstruct`?

`page1.java`

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
class pageBean{

    MyObject myObj;
    public String save(){FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(myObj,"obj");
    }
}
```

---

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
class pageBean{
@PostConstruct
public void init()
MyObject = (MyObject)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("obj");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your managed beans should have been `@ViewScoped`. Otherwise, you'd need to obtain it in (action)listener method such as `<f:event>`:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.init}" />
```

wherein you obtain the session object in `init()` method.

```
public void init() {
    obj = (Obj) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("obj");
}
```

Or maybe lazily loaded in a getter if your sole purpose is to access it in EL:

```
public Obj getObj() {
    if (obj == null) {
        obj = (Obj) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("obj");
    }

    return obj;
}
```

But this makes no sense as the session scoped object is just available directly in EL by `#{obj}` without the need for an intermediating bean such as `#{bean.obj}`.

At least, the whole design makes no sense. That's why I suggested that they should actually have been `@ViewScoped` instead.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)

Comment: i know that i must use the viewScope but my problem with it is that it has conflict with the ui:composition and ui:insert nad ui:include and i can't remove them so i am obliged to use sessionScope
my question is how can i make a call in another managedBean on page open (while navigating to the page) where in this way i can tell the managedBean to take another object rather than the object it has

Comment: Oh well yes, that is what I thought, but I'm too slow :)

Comment: ok so what can i do now
i think using a listner where the opened page takes the event but i don't no well how using this :S

Comment: As said, perform the job in (action)listener method (e.g. `<f:event type="preRenderView">` or in getter, if necessary by lazy loading. But doing this in getter makes no sense as session attributes are already directly available in EL by their name like `#{obj}`.

Comment: i will try reading the object in getter but can i know how to use the <f:event type="preRenderView"> and what its uses

Comment: its correct i used to read the object send by sessionmap in the getter and it worked i am so thakfull i will try the freRenderView maybe it will help me in another things
but does <f:event type="preRenderView"> takes a listener like this <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.invoce}"> where it calls this method before opening the page?

Comment: sorry for repeating my question : does <f:event type="preRenderView"> takes a listener like this <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.invoce}"> where it calls this method before opening the page?

Comment: Yes, just write code exactly as shown in my answer. See further also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for for other appliances of `<f:event type="preRenderView">`.